# CTRL+F searches last searched expression only but doesn't open quick find window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 (v14.0.25431.01 Update 3) and am experiencing the following behavior:

When clicking CTRL + F I am expecting that the quick find window opens, however the following happens:

After clicking CTRL + F no quick find window opens but instead it searches for the last string that I had put in the quick find field. So CTRL+F behaves like a 'find next' functionality right now.

I can manually open the quick find window: Edit > Find and Replace > Quick Find. If I edit the search expression the opened quick find window CTRL+F will find the next occurrence. However, once the quick find window is closed, CTRL+F will not re-open the quick window but rather perform a 'find next' on the last search expression.

Is there a way to get the functionality back that CTRL+F will open the quick find window?

Comment: First I try changing the scale to "Current Document" (I've noticed it usually happens after a CTRL-H Select/change all), if that doesn't get it, I hit escape a few times and it fixes on mine.  If that doesn't get it, restart usually works.  One or the other of those usually gets it for me, but I do get it too.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas @Aaron. I have restarted multiple times already but the behavior is still as described above. The scope for the search is set to "Current Document", yes. It is really strange that CTRL+F doesn't open the quick find window anymore.